# .create method not working with LocationRequest();

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

private LocationRequest mlocationrequest;    // initialziation

mlocationrequest= LocationRequest.create();    // here causing error

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UkhC.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was because I used the wrong import.

Try using the right one:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
```